# Is there a maximum depth level for nested objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Javascript has no problems with nesting an object within itself, i.e. if you have an object A, you can pass it as a property on object A:

```js
const nested = {};
nested.name = "hi";
nested.child = nested;

console.log(nested, nested.child, nested.child.child, "... and so on");
```

If you run this in the browser console, you can actually keep expanding the child property until... infinity?

Is there a limit to how deep objects an be nested, and what is it?

Comment: Well that will be infinite since you reference the same object reference. Not sure why you would want to do that.

Comment: For what you need this? I think only free memory is the limit

Comment: There is no limit to how far you can *follow* such nesting; there is a limit (memory) on how deep a structure you can build that doesn't employ such self-reference.

Comment: @zbyso purely out of curiosity and to understand better how the language works.

Comment: There is only one object `{/**id:1**/name: "hi", child: /**ref:1**/}`. Accessing `nested.child.child` is identical to `nested.child` they aren't different levels.

Comment: @epascarello that makes sense, didn't realise this was just using a reference to the same object. perhaps you could expand this comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit in the Javascript specification.

If you wanted to find a particular limit in a particular JS engine, you'd have to code a test and see if you could find a limit and running into a limit would probably not be related at all to nesting, but just to number of objects and memory used by them.

Comment: There's only one object. The limit would probably be in the length of the accessor statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no limit and you can freely nest further. But, if you keep consolelogging nested objects in nested objects and so on, the program would slow down due to limited memory.